# Can fan made anime based animations be asked in this community?

Tags: discussion

Anime has a lot of different meanings, that's why I'm asking. A few meanings I've come across through many years.

- Animation produced in Japan (many of the currently series known as "anime" are actually produced in Japan but animated in Korea)
- Animation written, animated and produced in Japan
- Animation animated in Japan but produced and written anywhere (ie: United States)
- An art style which can be animated and written anywhere but with specific characteristics and a style originated in Japan which makes it look "anime"
- Simply animation made anywhere (the original meaning of the word)

so this is why I'm asking, can fan made animations based in series currently known as "anime" be discussed in this community? There is a very interesting one going on right now

Comment: I'm pretty neutral opinion-wise on this but I'm just stopping by to say that this isn't a forum.

Comment: you might need to provide examples as i doubt and anything "fan made" is going to follow any established canon and acknowledged by the creators. *Magical Girl Noir Quest* if big fan made story but set totally outside the Madoka Universe in which Homura's terminated hundreds of timelines. the only example of a fan made work which may have been acknowledged by the creators is the Nanoha Fanfiction *The Legend of the Sword of the Day and the Sword of the Night* which was fan translated on nanofate.us before the author asked it to be taken down because it got published offically

Comment: sure fan made works arent going to be canon. As for acknowledged by the creators, not in the strict sense, but it's a known fact that many popular fan made creations end influencing the original canon story, though hardly ever officialy recognized (since it could be considered plagiarism)

Comment: and also many times people behind fan made works are incorporated in the official anime staff later

Comment: btw, crossovers can be official but they can't be canon either (since they would contradict all the universe's timelines) but I assume they are allowed to be asked here (such as Luffy, Goku and Toriko crossover)

Answer (score 7):

Take a moment and get to know the site better by reading [our tour page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tour).

When you do, you'll see that:

> Anime and Manga is a question and answer site for enthusiastic anime and manga fans.

If you read futher you will note that only point where there is a mention of forum is:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

On the topic of fan-made works, see our [policy on doujinshi](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267/should-questions-about-doujinshi-be-allowed). Also see [the criteria](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/354/63) for asking such questions.

Comment: okey, I wrote my question wrong, the point of my question is if you can ask questions and "get answers" about fan made anime based animations, not about if you can start discussions in the boards or not.