# Doujinshi Post on this site

Tags: discussion

Could we ask question related to Doujin on this site ? 
NSFW works and non-NSFW works doujin. Since there are some information on doujin that i want to discuss.

Comment: bit old here https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/267/2869 but I still think it should be allowed. Here is the criteria https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/354/2869

Comment: cool, thanks mate!

Comment: so, why there is no doujinshi tag ?

Comment: @gagantous [there is](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doujinshi)

Comment: Sorry... Must be I didnt spell the correct word

Comment: please noted that we don't want any NSFW stuff (image or text) on our site. If you need to add that, make sure you use spoiler tag to hide it

Comment: So can i type the author's name ? I mean nsfw doujin's author

Comment: yea the name is fine